# bouncing ball with friction (lower speed when touching the edge) problem in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I´m trying to make a bouncing ball with friction (lower speed when touching the edge) but there is a problem in my code. `d` is a var for the friction and every time the ellipse touch the edge 1 will be added to `d`. In another words, every time the ellipse touches the edge of the canvas, the friction should be higher.

My code:

```js
let x = 100;
let y = 100;
let xspeed = 5;
let yspeed = 5;

let r = 20;

let d = 0; //friction

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 300);
  frameRate(60);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(x, y, r * 2);
  x += xspeed;
  y += yspeed;

  if (d < 10 && d > -1) {
    if (x - d > width - r) {
      // width - r = 380
      xspeed = xspeed - d;
      xspeed = -xspeed;
      d++;
      console.log(d, x + d, y - d, x-d);
    }
    if (y - d > height - r -1) {
      //height - r = 280
      yspeed = yspeed - d;
      yspeed = -yspeed;
      d++;
      console.log(d, x + d, y - d, x-d);
    }

    if (x - 5 + d < r) {
      xspeed = xspeed + d;
      xspeed = -xspeed;
      d++;
      console.log(d, x + d, y - d, x-d);
    }
    if (y + d < r) {
      yspeed = yspeed + d;
      yspeed = -yspeed;
      d++;
      console.log(d, x + d, y - d, x-d);
    }
  }

  if (d == 11) {
    if (x > width - r || x < r) {
      xspeed = -xspeed;
    }
    if (y > height - r || y < r) {
      yspeed = -yspeed;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Could someone please correct my script?

Answer (score 0):

Friction occurs at the contact of an object with a surface. The phenomenon you're looking for is more like an inelastic impact.
I am hearing and trying to find recommendations.
Add sound that will be triggered with every bounch and lower amplitude sound when bounching ball's speed is lower